# Playwright cannot load local resource

Tags: python, google-chrome, playwright

This is the code:

```
class Render:
    def __init__(self):
        self.is_inital = False

    async def inital_browser(self):
        if self.is_inital: 
            return
        self.playwright = await async_playwright().start()
        self.browser = await self.playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True,args=["--no-sandbox","--disable-web-security","--allow-file-access-from-files","--allow-file-access"])
        self.is_inital = True

    async def screenshot(self, html, clip: dict) -> bytes:
        if not self.is_inital: 
            await self.inital_browser()
        page = await self.browser.new_page()
        await page.set_content(html)
        buffer = await page.screenshot(clip=clip)
        await page.close()
        return buffer
```

When I tried pass this HTML to the `Render.screenshot()`,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf_8">
<body>
      <img id="pic" src="/home/user/picture.png">
</body>
</html>
```

I got an empty picture.

I suspected it was chromium's issue, so I pass some args I searched when launching it, but it still didn't work.
Add `file://` before the path is useless too.

Which step did I do wrong?

Comment: I am also having the same issue